# Mongoose detailed query analytics

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-performance

I am working on a nodeJs/TS project using mongoose and I have performance issues on certain write operations.

The setup is:
mongoose 7.2.4
MongoDb Community Edition 4.0 (given by the cloud)
Application and DB run on the same private network on the cloud.

The document size varies between a few KB and around 1 MB. For smaller documents everything works quickly (<100ms), but starting from around 100KB things get slower and when surpassing 500KB we reach >4s or 5s on write operations (replaceOne).
Reading (e.g. findOne) is quick (<100ms).
The measurements were taken on nodeJs with console.time around the await of the mongoose query and with mongoose debug option.

The database on the cloud does not show any slow queries with a threshold of 100ms.

So combining the information it seems like bandwidth is not an issue (read is quick), database has no issues (no slow queries, also indexes are set accordingly) and still it ends up being really slow on large documents.

My only idea unverified is mongoose validations (the document uses nested schemas).

Is there a way to analyse/trace the "pipeline" from mongoose call to database and back in detail? Does anybody know of performance issues for the mongoose schema validations? We are using zod on the project and could go for a setup without mongoose if that is the only way to solve it.
Am I maybe missing some potential cause?

Help/hints/creative ideas are very welcome! Thanks a lot!